# isset() on codeigniter objects

Tags: codeigniter, session, object, isset

How can I achieve something that looks like:

```
if (isset($this->session->flashdata('user_profile'))) {}
```

without:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function flashdata() on a non-object in ...
```

The issue is that it returns an error when that thing isn't set rather than continue as one might expect. If it is set, everything works out fine.

...

I have also tried:

```
$tmp = $this->session->flashdata('user_profile');
if ($tmp) {
```

but to no avail.

Comment: Looks like `$this->session` is null.  Though you really should paste your entire error message.

Comment: are you using this code in your library ?

Answer (score 5):

you don't need `isset();` cause CI methods returns `false` or `true`

just do

```
 if($this->session->flashdata()){ }
```

and your error is cause you are surely not loading the session library:

so do this:

```
   $this->load->library('session');
if($this->session->flashdata()){ }
```

if you prefer (i preferr) you can autoload the session library changing this in your `config/autoload.php` file:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

so now you don't have to load anytime the session library cause CI autoloads that for you

Comment: That's the problem when migrating from pure PHP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the existence of $this->session first

`if (isset($this->session) && isset($this->session->flashdata('user_profile'))) {
}`

Answer (score 0):

For proper validation you must do this method. Weather the values becomes NULL sometimes.

```
$sessusr=$this->session->userdata('username'); 

 if(isset($sessusr) && trim($sessusr!=''))
 {

//to do

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you auto load the session library if not go to `config/autoload.php` open it and try to add session libarary it will look like this `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');` if you have auto loaded the  library than the alternative approach is:

```
if(!empty($this->session->flashdata('user_profile')): echo $this->session->flashdata('user_profile'); endif;
```